# I am trying to display the video in python using moviepy library but the video doesn't play

Tags: python, video-processing, moviepy

[code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZrys.png)

[From Command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqWdT.png)

I've tried many times to display the video using moviepy but it doesn't work I also tried to display it using command prompt but still the same problem..
So what should I do or what I am missing ?? help me please as this is a part of my graduation project and thank you.

### this is the code

```
from moviepy.editor import *


myvideo =  VideoFileClip('C:/Users/Sohayla/Desktop/PythonSourceCode/road_lane_line_detection-master/challenge.MP4').rotate(180)
myvideo.ipython_display()
```

Comment: No screenshots, please copy and paste the text into the post.

Comment: Agree with @Posh_Pumpkin, having code in images is a bad habit for multiple reasons. Regarding the question: I'd try `IPython.display.DisplayObject(data=myvideo)` or `IPython.display.DisplayObject(filename=myvideo)`. Overal, read [the documentation of the moviepy plugin](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) and that of the [ipython display module](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html). Find out what kind of an object is created by the first one and what kind is required by the second one.. make sure it is being fed the required input in the correct format.

Comment: PS: Thnx for adding the code in your question! Please, also apply the correct markup to enhance readability.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [the documentation of moviepy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/efficient_moviepy.html):

[image]

So, in your code:

```
from moviepy.editor import * 
myvideo = VideoFileClip('C:/Users/Sohayla/Desktop/PythonSourceCode/road_lane_line_detection-master/challenge.MP4').rotate(180) 
ipython_display(myvideo)
```

Should work..

Better would be:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip 
myvideo = VideoFileClip('C:/Users/Sohayla/Desktop/PythonSourceCode/road_lane_line_detection-master/challenge.MP4').rotate(180) 
ipython_display(myvideo)
```

Comment: it produce that the file size exceeds configured limit code insight feature not available in file _temp_.mp4

Comment: Try a smaller .mp4 file. Like this one for example: http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4

Comment: If it does work it probably means python display is only able to play video of a pre-defined size and yours is too large. You can probably use moviepy to downsize it.

Comment: If it does work with a smaller mp4 you might mark this as solved.

Comment: You can use `clip.resize()` to make the video smaller. Refer to the docs [here](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.resize.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the ipython_display you can use resize() function as video.resize() to change its height or width.

Video.resize(width=300) It will work fine.